# Access to the site without a port

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

My nginx listen on port 33333

```
listen 33333;
```

in /etc/nginx/sites-available/ I have:

```
server {
    listen 33333;
    server_name domain.com www.domain.com;
```

My website work only If I run:

> www.mydomain.com:33333

How to make it work well with the:

> www.domain.com

Without giving the port.

**Note: My port 80 is used by apache. I can not change it.**

Comment: "www.domain.com" is equivalent to "www.domain.com:80". 80 is the default port for HTTP. If you have another process already using port 80, you need either a separate IP address or a different port. Or you need to configure apache to proxy...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up nginx on port 80 make your site working normaly on port 80 a then configure nginx as reverse proxy to apache website runing on other (maybe 33333  on localhost)port. Both sites will be accessable from port 80 .

Or set up apache as reverse proxy to nginx (but i think first solution will be better fot site and server performance)

Some info about nginx reverse proxy :
http://kovyrin.net/2006/04/17/typical-nginx-configurations/
http://kovyrin.net/2006/05/18/nginx-as-reverse-proxy/

and much much more you can find in internet ... this topic is very well documented you should not have problems with configuring everything properly.

Answer (score 3):

In that case, you will need to configure Apache as a reverse proxy that hands the requests over to nginx on port 33333.

Answer (score 2):

You don't. The default port for http is 80. If you use another port, you must specify it.

Answer (score 1):

If.. and it's a big if, the sites that Apache is hosting has a different domain name to the site you're hosting with NginX, then it'd be possible to use Apache as a VirtualHost Reverse Proxy (proxypass etc,) to make this possible.

Failing that, you'll need another server, or a router to do some port translation or proxying.